# Select items based on values in Observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I have a select menu list that contains all available approval levels (self.approvalLevels observable array).

I have an ordered list that contains 3 selected approval levels (self.userSelectedApprovalLevels observable array). These are sorted by **priority**.

I want the items in self.userSelectedApprovalLevels observable to be marked as selected in the select menu list.

How do I do this?

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.approvalLevels = ko.observableArray([]); // observable array to store list of all available approval levels
  self.userSelectedApprovalLevels = ko.observableArray([]); // observable array to store list of approval levels selected by the user


  self.approvalLevels = ko.observableArray([{
      "ApprovalLevelID": 1,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Analyst"
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 2,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Supervisor"
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 3,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Tester"
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 4,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Manager"
    }
  ]);



  self.userSelectedApprovalLevels = ko.observableArray([{
      "ApprovalLevelID": 2,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Supervisor",
      "ApprovalLevelPriority": 0
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 1,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Analyst",
      "ApprovalLevelPriority": 1
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 3,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Tester",
      "ApprovalLevelPriority": 2
    }
  ]);


};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="approvalList">Select Approval Level(s)</label>
      <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="approvalLevelList" data-bind="options: approvalLevels, selectedOptions: userSelectedApprovalLevels, optionsText: 'ApprovalLevelName', optionsvalue: 'ApprovalLevelName'"></select>
      <small id="approvalLevelList" class="form-text text-muted">Select Approval Levels Required for this Task.</small>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Sort in Order of Approval level (Highest to Lowest):</p>
    <ol id="selectedApprovalLevelsList" data-bind="foreach: userSelectedApprovalLevels">
      <li class="list-group-item-info">
        <span data-bind="text: ApprovalLevelName"> </span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the selections to be correctly linked, they need to either *reference the same objects*, or *reference a primitive that can be compared using `===`*.

My advice is to create your source objects *once*, inside `self.approvalLevels`. To set the initial selection, you add references to the items in this array to the `selectedApprovalLevels` like so:

```
self.userSelectedApprovalLevels = ko.observableArray([
  self.approvalLevels()[0],
  self.approvalLevels()[1],
  self.approvalLevels()[2]
]);
```

Now, the selected list will not be sorted, but it will be correctly synced.

To sort the list, we create an additional `computed` layer that takes the selections and re-arranges them:

```
self.sortedSAL = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return self.userSelectedApprovalLevels().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.ApprovalLevelPriority - b.ApprovalLevelPriority;
  });
});
```

I put this together in the working example below.

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.approvalLevels = ko.observableArray([]); // observable array to store list of all available approval levels
  self.userSelectedApprovalLevels = ko.observableArray([]); // observable array to store list of approval levels selected by the user


  self.approvalLevels = ko.observableArray([

    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 1,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Analyst",
      "ApprovalLevelPriority": 1
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 2,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Supervisor",
      "ApprovalLevelPriority": 0
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 3,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Tester",
      "ApprovalLevelPriority": 2
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 4,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Manager",
      "ApprovalLevelPriority": 2
    }
  ]);



  self.userSelectedApprovalLevels = ko.observableArray(
    // Initial selections:
    self.approvalLevels().slice(0, 3)
  );
  
  self.sortedSAL = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.userSelectedApprovalLevels().sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.ApprovalLevelPriority - b.ApprovalLevelPriority;
    });
  });


};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="approvalList">Select Approval Level(s)</label>
      <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="approvalLevelList" data-bind="options: approvalLevels, selectedOptions: userSelectedApprovalLevels, optionsText: 'ApprovalLevelName', optionsvalue: 'ApprovalLevelName'"></select>
      <small id="approvalLevelList" class="form-text text-muted">Select Approval Levels Required for this Task.</small>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Sort in Order of Approval level (Highest to Lowest):</p>
    <ol id="selectedApprovalLevelsList" data-bind="foreach: sortedSAL">
      <li class="list-group-item-info">
        <span data-bind="text: ApprovalLevelName"> </span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit concerning requirement of two separate plain object lists**

If you're retrieving two lists from your server, it's best to create a client-side *viewmodel* that combines the data you need to be together. You can use the `<select>`'s list as the main source, and add `computed sortOrder` properties based on the second list:

```
sortOrder: ko.pureComputed(function() {
  var match = apSortData().find(function(item) {
    return item.ApprovalLevelID === data.ApprovalLevelID;
  });

  return match ? match.ApprovalLevelPriority : 0;
})
```

In a working example, in which the sort order data comes in 1 second after the source information:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  var apSortData = ko.observableArray([]);
  setTimeout(function() {
    // To show they are linked automatically
    apSortData(getSortOrderData());
  }, 1000)

  var ApprovalLevelVM = function(data) {
    return Object.assign(
      {}, 
      data, 
      {
        sortOrder: ko.pureComputed(function() {
          var match = apSortData().find(function(item) {
            return item.ApprovalLevelID === data.ApprovalLevelID;
          });
        
          return match ? match.ApprovalLevelPriority : 0;
        })
      }
    );
  };

  self.approvalLevels = ko.observableArray(
    getApprovalLevelData().map(ApprovalLevelVM)
  );

  self.userSelectedApprovalLevels = ko.observableArray(
    // Initial selections:
    self.approvalLevels().slice(0, 3)
  );

  self.sortedSAL = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.userSelectedApprovalLevels()
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.sortOrder() - b.sortOrder();
      });
  }).extend({"deferred": true});


};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

function getApprovalLevelData() {
  return [{
      "ApprovalLevelID": 1,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Analyst"
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 2,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Supervisor"
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 3,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Tester"
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 4,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Manager"
    }
  ];
};

function getSortOrderData() {
  return [{
      "ApprovalLevelID": 2,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Supervisor",
      "ApprovalLevelPriority": 0
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 1,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Analyst",
      "ApprovalLevelPriority": 1
    },
    {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 3,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Tester",
      "ApprovalLevelPriority": 2
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="approvalList">Select Approval Level(s)</label>
      <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="approvalLevelList" data-bind="options: approvalLevels, selectedOptions: userSelectedApprovalLevels, optionsText: 'ApprovalLevelName', optionsvalue: 'ApprovalLevelName'"></select>
      <small id="approvalLevelList" class="form-text text-muted">Select Approval Levels Required for this Task.</small>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Sort in Order of Approval level (Highest to Lowest):</p>
    <ol id="selectedApprovalLevelsList" data-bind="foreach: sortedSAL">
      <li class="list-group-item-info">
        <span data-bind="text: ApprovalLevelName + ' - '+ sortOrder()"> </span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem we have is that ApprovalLevelPriority does not exist in the source table for approvalLevels Observable. The userSelectedApprovalLevels Observable data is from a separate table source that does have ApprovalLevelPriority

Comment: I showed how to deal with 2 data-sources for 1 viewmodel in an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

so I think the gotcha on this one is that multi selected does not like to have an array of objects for the selectedOptions bindng. I attempted to get around that limitation by using a writable observable.  you could probably do a better job with the write part than the if statements I used but you can get the idea.

here is the working fiddle.https://jsfiddle.net/j3zk5uw9/3/

here is the writable observable.

```
  this.userSelectedApprovalLevelWritable = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
      var ApprovalLevelIDs = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.userSelectedApprovalLevels(), function(item) {
        return item.ApprovalLevelID;
      });
      return ApprovalLevelIDs.sort();

    },
    write: function(value) {
      self.userSelectedApprovalLevels.removeAll();
      for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        if (value[i] === 2) {
          self.userSelectedApprovalLevels.push({
            "ApprovalLevelID": 2, "ApprovalLevelName": "Supervisor",
            "ApprovalLevelPriority": 0
          })
        }
        if (value[i] === 1) {
          self.userSelectedApprovalLevels.push({
            "ApprovalLevelID": 1, "ApprovalLevelName": "Analyst",
            "ApprovalLevelPriority": 1
          })
        }
        if (value[i] === 3) {
          self.userSelectedApprovalLevels.push({
            "ApprovalLevelID": 3, "ApprovalLevelName": "Tester",
            "ApprovalLevelPriority": 2
          })
        }
        if (value[i] === 4) {
          self.userSelectedApprovalLevels.push({
            "ApprovalLevelID": 4, "ApprovalLevelName": "Manager",
            "ApprovalLevelPriority": 3
          })
        }
      }
    },
    owner: this
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The items in select menu are not selected.

Comment: I updated my answer now the items in the select menu are selected

Answer (score 0):

As @user3297291 said it's good to have the same object when you select. If there is no `ApprovalLevelPriority` you can add it to the object before pushing into the array but you need to have a logic to assign a priority number there

Here is my approach: 
You can add a change event to your selection and add an observable which hold the selectedOptions every time you select an item.

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/21dcxh2c/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="approvalList">Select Approval Level(s)</label>
         <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="approvalLevelList" data-bind="options: approvalLevels, selectedOptions: selectedApproval, optionsText: 'ApprovalLevelName', optionsvalue: 'ApprovalLevelName',event: {change: addApproval}"></select>
         <small id="approvalLevelList" class="form-text text-muted">Select Approval Levels Required for this Task.</small>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p>Sort in Order of Approval level (Highest to Lowest):</p>
      <ol id="selectedApprovalLevelsList" data-bind="foreach: userSelectedApprovalLevels">
         <li class="list-group-item-info">
            <span data-bind="text: ApprovalLevelName"> </span>
         </li>
      </ol>
   </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var viewModel = function() {
   var self = this;

   self.approvalLevels = ko.observableArray([]); // observable array to store list of all available approval levels
   self.userSelectedApprovalLevels = ko.observableArray([]); // observable array to store list of approval levels selected by the user
    self.selectedApproval = ko.observable();
   self.userSelectedApprovalLevels = ko.observableArray([]);

   self.approvalLevels = ko.observableArray([{
      "ApprovalLevelID": 1,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Analyst"
   }, {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 2,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Supervisor"
   }, {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 3,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Tester"
   }, {
      "ApprovalLevelID": 4,
      "ApprovalLevelName": "Manager"
   }]);

   self.addApproval = function() {
      var duplicate = false;
      var obj = self.selectedApproval()[0]
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.userSelectedApprovalLevels(), function(element) {
         if (obj.ApprovalLevelID == element.ApprovalLevelID) {
            return duplicate = true
         }
      });
      if (!duplicate) {
          // here you can add your priority to the object 
          // right now I am adding the ApprovalLevelID as ApprovalLevelPriority you probably will have your logic 
         obj.ApprovalLevelPriority = obj.ApprovalLevelID
         self.userSelectedApprovalLevels.push(obj)
      } //else you can remove if it already exists
   }

   self.sortSelection = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.userSelectedApprovalLevels().sort(function(a, b) {
         return a.ApprovalLevelPriority > b.ApprovalLevelPriority;
      });
   });

};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```